# Problem combining Reactive Framework (Rx) queries to provide correct UI behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, system.reactive

I'm trying to remove the more tradition event handlers from a Silverlight application in favour of using a number of Rx queries to provide a better, easier to manage, behavioural abstraction.

The problem that I need to solve, but can't quite crack it the way I want, is getting the behaviour of a search screen working. It's pretty standard stuff. This is how it should behave:

- I have a **text box** where the user can enter the **search text**.
- If there is **no text (or whitespace only)** then the **search button** is **disabled**.
- When there is **non-whitespace text** then the **search button** is **enabled**.
- When the user **clicks search** the **text box** and the **search button** are both **disabled**.
- When the **results come back** the **text box** and the **search button** are both **enabled**.

I have these observables (created via some extension methods over the standard events) to work with:

```
IObservable<IEvent<TextChangedEventArgs>> textBox.TextChangedObservable()
IObservable<IEvent<RoutedEventArgs>> button.ClickObservable()
IObservable<IEvent<LoadingDataEventArgs>> dataSource.LoadingDataObservable()
IObservable<IEvent<LoadedDataEventArgs>> dataSource.LoadedDataObservable()
```

I have these queries that work at the moment:

```
IObservable<bool> dataSourceIsBusy =
    dataSource.LoadingDataObservable().Select(x => true)
    .Merge(dataSource.LoadedDataObservable().Select(x => false));

IObservable<string> textBoxText =
    from x in textBox.TextChangedObservable()
    select textBox.Text.Trim();

IObservable<bool> textBoxTextIsValid =
    from text in textBoxText
    let isValid = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
    select isValid;

IObservable<string> searchTextReady =
    from x in button.ClickObservable()
    select textBox.Text.Trim();
```

And then these subscriptions to wire it all up:

```
buttonIsEnabled.Subscribe(x => button.IsEnabled = x);
dataSourceIsBusy.Subscribe(x => textBox.IsEnabled = !x);
searchTextReady.Subscribe(x => this.ExecuteSearch(x));
```

(I do keep references to the disposables returned by the `Subscribe` methods. I have `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` added to each observable to ensure the code runs on the UI thread.)

Now while this works there is one thing that bugs me. The select statement in `searchTextReady` calls `textBox.Text.Trim()` to obtain the current trimmed search text, but I already have done this in the `textBoxText` observable. I really don't want to repeat myself so I would like to create a query that combines these observables and this is where I'm failing.

When I try the following query I get re-entrant calls to execute the search:

```
IObservable<string> searchTextReady =
    from text in textBoxText
    from x in button.ClickObservable()
    select text;
```

The following query it seems to work for the first query, but then each time I change the text in the text box thereafter the search is automatically executed without clicking the search button:

```
IObservable<string> searchTextReady =
    from text in button.ClickObservable()
        .CombineLatest(textBoxText, (c, t) => t)
    select text;
```

The following query requires a further text change to occur after the search button is clicked and then fails to run again:

```
IObservable<string> searchTextReady =
    from text in textBoxText
      .SkipUntil(button.ClickObservable())
      .TakeUntil(dataSource.LoadingDataObservable())
    select text;
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help on this question. I couldn't give anyone the answer because I found that the solution was to use the `.Switch()` operator and no-one gave that answer.

Since I did find the answer to my problem I thought I would post it here to help anyone else trying to do what I've done.

Part of my original problem what that I didn't want to repeat code. So I introduced a `Func<string, bool> textIsValid` that could be re-used in my `IObservable<bool> textBoxTextIsValid` and in my desired `IObservable<string> searchTextReady`.

```
Func<string, bool> textIsValid = t => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(t);
```

Now `searchTextReady` can be defined as follows:

```
IObservable<string> searchTextReady =
    (from text in textBoxText
     select (from x in button.ClickObservable().TakeUntil(textBoxText)
             where textIsValid(text)
             select text)
    ).Switch();
```

So `.Switch()` works by taking an `IObservable<IObservable<string>>` and flattening it out into an `IObservable<string>`.

It's easy to create an `IObservable<IObservable<string>>` - just write a query against an observable and select some other observable.

For example:

```
IObservable<Unit> xs= ...;
IObservable<string> ys= ...;

IObservable<IObservable<string>> zss = xs.Select(x => ys);

IObservable<string> zs = zss.Switch();
```

But this doesn't do anything particularly useful.

If it's changed around as:

```
IObservable<Unit> clicks = ...;
IObservable<string> texts = ...;
Func<string, bool> isValid = ...;

IObservable<IObservable<string>> zss =
    texts.Select(t =>
        clicks
            .Take(1)
            .TakeUntil(texts)
            .Where(x => isValid(t))
            .Select(x => t));

IObservable<string> zs = zss.Switch();
```

The final observable can be described as:

> "Whenever the text changes take only
>   the next click provided that the text
>   doesn't change again and such that the text
>   is valid and then select the value
>   that the text changed to."

I hope this answer helps someone else.

Answer (score 5):

These kind of things are tricky on their own, so I ended up writing [an M-V-VM + Rx library](http://github.com/xpaulbettsx/ReactiveXaml) to help me out - it turns out that with this library, this task is pretty easy; here's the whole code, [my blog](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/category/programming/reactive-extensions/) explains more about how these classes work:

```
public class TextSearchViewModel
{
    public TextSearchViewModel
    {
        // If there is no text (or whitespace only) then the search button is disabled.
        var isSearchEnabled = this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SearchText)
            .Select(x => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(x.Value));

        // Create an ICommand that represents the Search button
        // Setting 1 at a time will make sure the Search button disables while search is running
        DoSearch = new ReactiveAsyncCommand(isSearchEnabled, 1/*at a time*/);

        // When the user clicks search the text box and the search button are both disabled.
        var textBoxEnabled = DoSearch.ItemsInflight
            .Select(x => x == 0);

        // Always update the "TextboxEnabled" property with the latest textBoxEnabled IObservable
        _TextboxEnabled = this.ObservableToProperty(textBoxEnabled, 
            x => x.TextboxEnabled, true);

        // Register our search function to run in a background thread - for each click of the Search
        // button, the searchResults IObservable will produce a new OnNext item
        IObservable<IEnumerable<MyResult>> searchResults = DoSearch.RegisterAsyncFunction(textboxText => {
            var client = new MySearchClient();
            return client.DoSearch((string)textboxText);
        });

        // Always update the SearchResults property with the latest item from the searchResults observable
        _SearchResults = this.ObservableToProperty(searchResults, x => x.SearchResults);
    }

    // Create a standard INotifyPropertyChanged property
    string _SearchText;
    public string SearchText {
        get { return _SearchText; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.SearchText, value); }
    }

    // This is a property who will be updated with the results of an observable
    ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _TextboxEnabled;
    public bool TextboxEnabled {
        get { return _TextboxEnabled.Value; }
    }

    // This is an ICommand built to do tasks in the background
    public ReactiveAsyncCommand DoSearch { get; protected set; }

    // This is a property who will be updated with the results of an observable
    ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IEnumerable<MyResult>> _SearchResults;
    public IEnumerable<MyResult> SearchResults {
        get { return _SearchResults.Value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like what you've done here, so I've given you an up-vote, but it doesn't directly answer my question so I'm not ready to accept it as the answer. If nothing else comes along I'll have a look at adapting what you've done for my needs. Right now though this would represent a fairly large code change. Good work though!

Comment: Feel free to steal bits and pieces from the codebase - the important idea though is that you shouldn't be using Rx at the Event/View level, it's far better (and testable!) to use it at the ViewModel level and be making decisions on property change notifications and command invocations.

Comment: Also, would adding a StartWith help you here, in setting the initial state of your observables?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ForkJoin](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc3)

Something like:

```
    IObservable<string> searchTextReady = Observable.ForkJoin(textBoxText, button.ClickObservable());
    searchTextReady.Subscribe( ....
```

Comment: Sorry, but `ForkJoin` only combines the last values of the observables (which also need to be of the same type). I want the `searchTextReady` observable to fire every time the search button is clicked and return the latest, not last, `textBoxText` value. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`DistinctUntilChanged` is what you are looking for.

E.g. something like this should work:

```
// low level observables
var dataSourceLoading = ... // "loading" observable
var dataSourceLoaded = ... // "loaded" observable
var textChange = Observable.FromEvent<TextChangedEventArgs>(MyTextBox, "TextChanged");
var click = Observable.FromEvent<RoutedEventArgs>(MyButton, "Click");

// higher level observables
var text = textChange.Select(_ => MyTextBox.Text.Trim());
var emptyText = text.Select(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
var searchInProgress = dataSourceLoading.Select(_ => true).Merge(dataSourceLoaded.Select(_ => false));

// enable/disable controls
searchInProgress.Merge(emptyText)
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(v => MyButton.IsEnabled = !v);
searchInProgress
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(v => MyTextBox.IsEnabled = !v);

// load data 
click
    .CombineLatest(text, (c,t) => new {c,t})
    .DistinctUntilChanged(ct => ct.c)
    .Subscribe(ct => LoadData(ct.t));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. The `DistinctUntilChanged` only allows a single search. When I change the text and try to search again the observable doesn't load the data.

Comment: The only reason why the observable in my example would produce only 1 value is that "c" coming out of "click" is always the same. Did you try the code exactly as shown in my response?

Comment: Had a few minutes to compile the code (see: http://s3.amazonaws.com/silverlight/DistinctUntilChanged.html) As you can see it works as expected (e.g. loads the source every time user clicks a button)